# Adcionar um Caracter ao valor de uma coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível incluir um conjunto de caracteres ao final do dado de uma coluna.

Por exemplo:

```
'Coluna 1- Quantidade
 |10000
 |20000
 |15000
 |20000
```

Eu quero extrair uma query onde eu possa exibir esse dado com um caracter depois do número dessa forma.

```
'Coluna 1- Quantidade
 |10000 Tons
 |20000 Tons
 |15000 Tons
 |20000 Tons
```

É possível?

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a concatenação adicionando o texto:

```
SELECT CAST(quantidade AS NVARCHAR) + ' Tons' FROM tabela
```

Comment: Olá Marcelo. Muito obrigado. Deu certíssimo